# Search for number sequence

Tags: perl, awk

say you have a file1.csv containing 5 million lines, each line has 8 random numbers separated by comma. And you have this sequence `7,152,13,11,42,5,7`

How to output the lines in file1.csv containing 3 or more numbers from that sequence along with line number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting. I'd use awk

```
awk -F, -v seq="7,152,13,11,42,5,7" '
    BEGIN {
        n = split(seq, a)
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) num[a[i]]=1
    }
    { 
        n=0
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { 
            if ($i in num) n++
            if (n == 3) {
                print
                break
            }
        }
    }
' bigfile
```

Predictably, perl is much more terse

```
export seq="7,152,13,11,42,5,7"
perl -F, -lane '
    BEGIN {%nums = map {$_ => 1} split /,/, $ENV{seq}} 
    print if scalar(grep {exists $nums{$_}} @F) >= 3
' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `python` script to do the job :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
nums = set('7,152,13,11,42,5,7'.split(','))
with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
    f = enumerate(f, start=1)
    for i, line in f:
        if len(set.intersection(nums, set(line.split(',')))) >= 3:
            print str(i) + ': ' + line.rstrip()
```

- The `set`, `nums` will contain the numbers we want to match
- We have created an `enumerate` object to get the line number and iterate over the lines
- `set.intersection(nums, set(line.split(',')))` gets us the common numbers among from the `nums` and `line`
- If there are 3 or more numbers from that sequence occur in the line `if len(....) >= 3`, then the line number and the line will be printed.

The output will be like :

```
1: 7,152,13,11,42,5,45
2: 7,152,1,5,7,34,44
3: 7,152,13,11,42,5,7
5: 11,42,5,7,7,152,13
```

Also considering the numbers do not have to come in the exact order mentioned, they can come in any order.

Comment: That would obviously be my trick as well :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yeah..it is obvious :)